# Use Parameter Values and Group by

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to develop a report with setting parameters on filter,

and will directly effect on report result

But now is fail when I want to group 【CalculateTransactionRange】this columns :

[image]

I only want to show every shop's 【CalculateTransactionRange】and AMT

[Sample Data](https://onedrive.live.com/?id=62F9CC35AD7C49C7%219498&resid=62F9CC35AD7C49C7%219498&redeem=aHR0cHM6Ly8xZHJ2Lm1zL3UvcyFBc2RKZkswMXpQbGl5aHF2ZGF4bnloTXdMQUg3P2U9Nm5oZUlL&migratedtospo=true&cid=62f9cc35ad7c49c7&v=validatepermission)

I try to use Summarize but seems can't get parameters in table...

[image]